# Using JAXB for multiple root XML elements in one file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Considering an input XML file with following content:

```
<organization>
    <director>
        <fname>Dan</fname>
        <lname>Schman</lname>
    </director>
</organization>  
<organization>
    <director>
        <fname>fan</fname>
        <lname>Heman</lname>
    </director>
</organization>
<organization>
    <director>
        <fname>Ban</fname>
        <lname>Sheman</lname>
    </director>
</organization>
```

Is it possible to use JAXB to unmarshall this input file with multiple root elements? Is there any better tool that can be used to achieve this?

I am familiar with using JAXB for a file containing a single root element, but how do I go about unmarshalling when an input file has multiple root elements as given above?

Answer (score 3):

Your input "XML" file is not valid XML. XML has only one single root element. JAXB can only unmarshal valid XML files.

I recommend to use valid XML.

Otherwise you will have to split the document manually into multiple valid XML documents (could be in-memory).
But this approach leads to more code you will have to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to wrap your xml into one big root element like this

```
<root>
   <organization>
      ...
   </organization>
   <organization>
      ...
   </organization>
</root>
```

Then you can use an `XMLInputFactory` to create a `XMLStreamReader` too loop each `organization` element and unmarshal each of it using the unmashaller method:

```
yourUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLStreamReader reader);
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid XML has only one root element.

Write a small pre-processor that chunks your input almost-XML into smaller valid XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

The file format will be as described in my question. It has multiple XMLs in it (but with same tags).

I have solved this problem, I am reading the XML file one message at a time, that is,    `<organization>...</organization>` into a string And then passing this string to unmarshaller as

```
   Organisation org = (Organisation) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader("xml string here"));
```